# PHP ssh2 storing connection data

Tags: php, ssh, drupal-7, connection, command

How can I store connection data in php?
I'd like to access is later, but as far as I know, storing resource data in session is not possible.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm going to say "no", but I am also interested in some more details of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm going to execute several commands via ssh2 in drupal, and I wonder how I can store connection data to prevent opening connection each time in ajax callback.

Comment: I really hope you aren't doing this on a public facing webserver. You can't have persistent resources open between PHP executions. Not without a permanent daemon running and PHP 5.5 so you can use sendmsg.

Comment: Well, sendmsg probably won't be needed, but daemon yes.

Comment: This is only available in admin, not outside.

Comment: What are the kinds of commands you're issuing? Would it not be more prudent to use AJAX to queue up jobs in a database and then perform them using a cron job?

Comment: Admin or not, it is still a dangerous idea to expose that level of power to a browser if the commands are coming from it.